# Barcode scanning in Espresso

Tags: android-espresso, barcode-scanner

**Context:**
I have to write an automated test in Espresso to scan barcodes from the app screen (as in image #1) by pressing the infra red (IR) scanner button of the device. Once scanned, if the bc is not valid, the screen changes to image #2.

**My question:**
As scanning is not an UI element, how to programmatically scan a barcode in Espresso ?

**System information:**
Device: Honeywell CT45XP running Android 11.0

**Usage:**

0. At screen #1 (image attached) the app is ready to scan a barcode
1. Scan a linear barcode (e.g. MJ123456789CA) by pressing the IR scanner button of the device
2. On scan, if the barcode is not valid screen #2 (image atatched) is appeared

**Image #1:**
[image: Image #1]

**Image #2:**
[image: Image #2]